# How should I resolve warning app:hiltAggregateDepsDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, wiki

## How should I resolve this warning in my project :

> Task :app:hiltAggregateDepsDebug
> WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\Aniket.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3495027e3835bf7dc000a48060b35365\transformed\core-1.9.0-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
> Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/core/R$styleable'
> Example of support library reference: 'android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Default'
> [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\Aniket.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3495027e3835bf7dc000a48060b35365\transformed\core-1.9.0-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.

Comment: I have a similar warning, which is follow with a failed tasked concerning `:app:hiltAggregateDepsDebug`. May I ask what version of hilt you are using? I am using 2.35 for the app and 2.45 for the plugin...